# Train-and-Track thought experiment in Taylor & Wheeler: A plain initial difficulty

Tags: special-relativity, spacetime, foundations

The book *Spacetime Physics* by E. F. Taylor and J. A. Wheeler belongs to the [recommended sources](https://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bresource-recommendations%5D+%22taylor%22+%22wheeler%22) on the topic of the special theory of relativity. (Also, meanwhile, some of its editions are readily accessable [here](https://www.eftaylor.com/spacetimephysics/) or [there](https://phys.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Relativity/Spacetime_Physics_(Taylor_and_Wheeler)).) In the section titled *"Relativity of Simultaneity"* it offers a presentation of [*"Einstein's famous Train Paradox"*](https://phys.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Relativity/Spacetime_Physics_(Taylor_and_Wheeler)/03%3A_Same_Laws_for_All/3.04%3A_Relativity_of_Simultaneity) which, however, differs from [Einstein's original description](https://einsteinpapers.press.princeton.edu/vol6-doc/469) in subtle but arguably quite interesting ways.

Now, while preparing a question arising from those subtle distinctions, I just stumbled over a rather plain difficulty with Taylor & Wheeler's version, which ought to be resolved first, by asking hereby separately. This difficulty is laid open by selecting and comparing just two brief quotes from Taylor & Wheeler's presentation, namely

(1)
from the beginning of the setup prescription:

> *"Lightning strikes the front and back ends of a rapidly moving train, leaving char marks on the train and on the track [...] (Figure  3.4.1)."*

and

(2)
a second statement (which is part of a more comprehensive *"conclusion"* concerning simultaneity; but which, as quoted, doesn't itself mention "simultaneity" at all):

> *"An observer standing on the ground halfway between the two char marks on the track [...] concludes that the two lightning bolts struck the track [...]."*

The quoted setup prescription (1) and the quoted second statement (2) appear **in conflict about exactly who** was (or: exactly which material points were) supposed to be *"struck by lightning"*, or (equivalently) *"struck by lightning bolts"*, resp., namely

- either exclusively the front and back ends of the train (as suggested by the quoted setup prescription (1) itself, and, indeed, apparently as shown in *Figure 3.4.1*);
- or including constituents of the track as well (according to statement (2)).

#### My question(s):

Is the statement of quote (2) to be considered imprecise ?

And for the purpose of studying SR, the notion of simultaneity, and analyzing Taylor & Wheeler's presentation choices in the Train-and-Track thought experiment in more detail:

Can statement of quote (2) be expressed more precisely as:

> "An observer standing on the ground halfway between the two char marks on the track [...] concludes that **the track had received these two char marks** [...].",

where the setup prescription (1) is accordingly understood more specificly as

> "Lightning strikes the front and back ends of a rapidly moving train, leaving char marks on the train, **and such that char marks are also (as good as) instantly applied to track constituents coincident with the train front end, or the train back end, resp., being struck by lightning** [...] as shown in *Figure 3.4.1*."

?

Answer (score 2):

About twenty years ago, my wife and I saw lightning strike a gorse bush about 400 metres from where we were standing. It was extremely scary. The bush went up in smoke in an instant and the ground a metre or so around it was blackened. So yes, if lightning strikes the two ends of the train it could well leave scorch marks on both the train and the adjacent ground at the same instant.

I can't see any conflict between the two statements. The first says quite clearly that the lightning leaves marks on the train and on the track. The second mentions an observer on the ground looking at the marks on the track, the high speed train and its marks having presumably vanished in the distance.

Comment: Marco Ocram: _"So yes,"_ -- I like that ... _"if lightning strikes the two ends of the train it"_ -- What exactly do you refer to by "it" ?? The track being struck by lightning, or "only" being in contact with some hot piece of train?  (Taylor/Wheeler don't seem to specify that.) _"could well leave scorch marks on both the train and the adjacent ground at the same instant."_ -- Well, the track becomimg char-marked is undisputed and not the OP question. The question is instead about whether or not the the track is "struck by lightning (bolts)". [contd.]

Comment: Marco Ocram: _"I can't see any conflict [...]"_ -- A figure which is faithful to statement (2) **should show 4 flash signs**, and **not only 2** (as does Fig. 3.4.1). Perhaps you mean to raise the possibility that already quote (1) incl. Fig. 3.4.1 are imprecise, namely by **not explicitly** mentioning and showing the track being struck by lightning. (If I edit the OP in order to account for this possibility, too, ... that'll be kinda fun!)

Comment: The thought experiment will work out in the same way regardless of how you interpret the precise details. At each end of the train the creation of two char marks coincide, more or less, in spacetime with a flash. Granted there might be a tiny propagation delay between the lightning charring the train and charring the track, but it can be ignored for the purpose of the thought experiment.

Comment: Marco Ocram: _"The thought experiment will work out the same regardless [...] Granted there might be a tiny delay [...]"_ -- That's trying to anticipate my upcoming "more subte question" advertised in the OP. I can be upfront: It's not at all about that tiny, negligible delay. It's about the track char marks and the train end char marks being (thought as) distinct, and **being available for discourse** at all, and for **expressing** the conclusions from the experimental observation **in more nuanced ways**; other than having only the "featureless" `A` and `B` of Einstein, 1917, §9 to work with

Comment: I will look forward to the new question. Whatever your concern is, I am sure it can be resolved by a simple change to the experiment. How about replacing the lightening with a small bomb filled with ink exploding at each end of the train, leaving an ink blot on the track. Or a harpoon gun coupled with a flash bulb firing a harpoon directly down into the ground.

Comment: Since my brief  mentioning of _"§9"_ appears too cryptic, here's the point once again more fully: It's (always only) about having **the explicit notions and explicit names** of `A` and `B` precisely as Einstein introduces them already in the relevant §8 (namely as "embankmant places") **and** of `A'` and `B'` precisely as Einstein introduces them (albeit unfortunately only in §10) together available for (stating and) analyzing the train experiment of §9; contrasting with Einstein himself who muddles these features in his awfully oversimplified [_"Fig. 1"_](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5WjS0.gif).

Comment: Understood. But is your point just that Einstein didn't do a great job of explaining himself, or is there more to it?

Comment: Marco Ocram: _"[...] just that Einstein didn't do a great job"_ -- In §9. _"or is there more to it?"_ -- Basic is §8:$$\rm{Lightning~struck~railway~spots~A,~B.~Identify~M~at~mid~ point~of~distance~AB,~watching~both.\\  If~M~sees~A's~flashing~and~B's~flashing~together~then~these~were~simultaneous;~and~if~not~together~then~not~simultaneous.}$$Is this incomplete or deficient? Could anyone's judgement about simultaneity or non-simultaneity of A's flashing and B's flashing oppose M's judgement? Does it concern entire events, incl. all trains (locomotive or caboose), planes, automobiles? No-no-no!

Answer (score 0):

The top picture of Fig. 3.4.1 which accompanies Taylor-&-Wheeler's descriptions (1) as well as (2) appears to show and to support description (1) over description (2):

[image: Taylor-Wheeler-Spacetime-Physics-Fig3.4.1 Front end and back end of the train were struck by lightning etc.]

The front end and the back end of the train were specificly struck by lightning, while the two sections of the track which (one each) took part in one, or the other, of the corresponding two events as well were not themselves struck by lightning, but merely received char marks.

(
This specific distinction between indications of the train ends and indications of track sections may of course present some idealization, which is however typical in thought-experimental descriptions and which here provides the concrete didactic advantage of making [Einstein's definition of simultaneity](https://einsteinpapers.press.princeton.edu/vol6-trans/283?highlightText=simultaneous)
directly and separately applicable in the two relevant cases:

- to the train ends having been struck by lightning, with the non-simultaneity of these indications being asserted by the train observer in the middle between the train ends, and
- to the track sections having received char marks, with the simultaneity of these indications being asserted by the track observer in the middle between these marks.

)